# iTextSharp - acroform field encoding

Tags: encoding, itext

I'm trying to fill out a AcroForm's textfield with iTextSharp. The Acroform textfield was created also by iTextSharp by this piece of code:

```
TextField Field = new TextField(OutputWriter, FieldPos, "MyField");
OutputWriter.AddAnnotation(Field.GetTextField()); // OutputWriter is writing to form.pdf
```

I fill the form using this code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("form.pdf");
PdfStamper filledOutForm = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream("filled_form.pdf", FileMode.Create));

AcroFields form = filledOutForm.AcroFields;
form.SetField("MyField", "some unicode data");
```

However, when I open filled_form.pdf in Acrobat Reader, unicode characters are not visible unless I edit manually the field (e.g. I append a character by hand to the field).

I also tried to set field's font by:

```
BaseFont fieldFontRoman = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\times.ttf",
                                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                                BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
form.SetFieldProperty("MyField", "textfont", fieldFontRoman, null);
```

Then, when I open filled_form.pdf in Acrobat Reader, everything looks fine unless I edit manually the field. After that, non unicode characters disappear (they change into blank spaces). They are here in the field because if I copy whole content of the field by CTRL + C and paste it to notepad, I can see all characters.

Please advise. I would like to see all characters in the field without the need of editing the field manually and of course after editing it manually I would like no characters to disappear.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Set the SubstitutionFont after creating the PdfStamper:

```
stamper.AcroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(myFont.BaseFont);
```

Comment: Acrobat reader is able to set Unicode field values on the same document without resorting to a substitution font. Isn't there a better way to solver this?

Comment: Also setting the substitution font does not seem to work when you flatten the document.