# PDF - Text not showing when filling form

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm facing a problem when filling a PDF form using iTextSharp, I'm using the following code to fill the PDF form:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(Properties.Resources.ConfirmationFees);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(folderPath + "\\" +fileName, FileMode.Create));

AcroFields pdfFFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

pdfFFields.SetFieldProperty("Text1", "textsize", 10.0f, null);

pdfFFields.SetField("Text1", serialNumber.ToString("D6") + "№");

pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;

// close the pdf
pdfStamper.Close();
```

When I open the PDF, I have to select the textField and go to Properties, select border color or fill color, and click on "No Color". or just simply add a character to the textField.

I've tried to set the border and background color of the textField to null, but without luck.

So, how can I solve this problem without doing the mentioned way?

Comment: If you are using Unicode text, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10274659/298573

Answer (score 2):

How did you create your form? If with Open/Libre Office, then the forms are a little bit crappy. You may need to add this line:

```
pdfFFields.setGenerateAppearances(true);
```

In your specific C# snippet, that would be:

```
pdfFFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
```

See also:

- [AcroForm values missing after flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526634/acroform-values-missing-after-flattening/)
- [PdfCopy and form values with iText: form values not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231797/pdfcopy-and-form-values-with-itext-form-values-not-visible)

If this doesn't solve your problem, you need to tell us which version of iTextSharp you're using. If it's older than 5.5.1, please upgrade.

Comment: I'm using iTextSharp V. 5.4.1.0, I've check the `pdfFFields.GenerateAppearances = true;` and it does not solve my problem. Also, I'm not flatten the PDF. I've created the PDF using inDesign, created a textfield in it and using the file as a template for my desktop application.

Comment: Share the PDF please, also tell us which font you use.

Comment: Solved my issue...  A template created with Acrobat Pro worked fine but then I switched to using an alternative editor.  The template saved by the non-Adobe editor necessitated the this additional line of code.